# Using ne to replace dimenticare di [infinitive]

Tags: particles

One possible usage of the particle ne is to replace prepositional phrases introduced by 'di'.

In the following example:

> Hai dimenticato di fare i compiti? Sì, ne ho dimenticato.

Is there any problem replacing the prepositional phrase 'di fare i compiti' with 'ne'? How does it sound to native speakers?

Answer (score 4):

In this sentence the usage of "ne" is not fully correct and sounds a bit ugly. The correct form would be:

> Hai dimenticato di fare i compiti? Sì, **me ne sono** dimenticato

or

> Hai dimenticato di fare i compiti? Sì, **l'ho** dimenticato

or

> Hai dimenticato di fare i compiti? Sì, ho dimenticato

I found some examples about the usage of "ne" on: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ne#Italian

Comment: I appreciate your answer. I would still like to understand why ne can't be used to replace the 'di + [inf]' in this example, however. That is one of the major uses of ne, and I'm not sure why it doesn't work in the example I gave.

Comment: In Italian you can use the verb "dimenticare" (to forget) in a passive form, like on my first example, in which:

me ne sono dimenticato = mi sono dimenticato di essi > I forgot about them.

instead:

l'ho dimenticato > I forgot it

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a bit complicated to explain why you cannot always replace DI+something with NE

Ho voglia di questo = Ne ho voglia, ok
Ho parlato di questo = Ne ho parlato, ok

But

Ammetto di aver sbagliato = Ne ammetto ... mmmh, definitely wrong.
Ammetto di aver sbagliato = Lo ammetto.

Why?

Because actually you are saying:

Ammetto che ho sbagliato, ammetto questo = lo ammetto.

So: if verb+di+verb can be transformed in verb+che+verb
then, maybe, you shouldn't use NE.

Another example: Ti chiedo di venire = Ti chiedo che tu venga = Te lo chiedo.

It sounds normal to me BUT something doesn't match.

Some verbs with a reflexive form can be followed by CHE and DI and normally the work with NE.

Mi dimentico sempre che devo mettere la sveglia = Mi dimentico sempre di mettere la sveglia = Me ne dimentico sempre.

How actually does it work?